# How to use ssh tunnel just for specific sites

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-tunnel

I have ubuntu server that i use as ssh tunnel to avoid internet filtering but some sites are filtered in my server so I bought another server in another country and i want to redirect those filtered sites to that server
IP's of the sites are constant.

Comment: so what goes into a tunnel is determined by IP routing, so you can say "if the IP address is 101.1.1.2, then route to tunnel2" but cannot be controlled by domain names, so if you know the IPs for the sites you want to visit via your second tunnel you can route traffic that way, but if the IP address is changing periodically or uses multi-homed hosting, this will probably not be a reliable solution.

Comment: "ssh tunnel" – Do you mean `ssh -D` i.e. SOCKS? or what setup exactly? For browsers a [proxy auto-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) may be what you need.

Comment: Look up "Split Tunnel" vpn for examples

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.